# Magento - $_orders = Mage::getResourceModel outputs the SQL string - Recent.php

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to output more orders on the front end of /customer/account Recent Orders grid.

The code in /Mage/Sales/Order/Block/Recent.php says this

```
<?php  $_orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')            
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_firstname', 'order_address/firstname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_lastname', 'order_address/lastname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
        ->setPageSize(5)        
        ->load();
?>
```

When I edit number ->load(10) it outputs a string of the query that was created. There is no echo anywhere in Recent.php

It also does not add 10 Orders, just stays at default 5. What am I missing?

I tried putting this straight into recent.phtml

```
<?php  $_orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')            
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_firstname', 'order_address/firstname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_lastname', 'order_address/lastname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
        ->setPageSize('10')        
        ->load('10');
?>
```

And it changes the number of orders to 10, but still outputs the SQL query.

**Query**

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.customer_id = '1') AND (state IN('new', 'processing', 'complete', 'closed', 'canceled', 'holded', 'payment_review')) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10 10
```

Any ideas?

Comment: first, you should not edit core files. if you want to modify override that. and try `load()` and `setPageSize(10)` for more orders

Comment: yup this worked. Thanks! How do I make your comment into an answer?

PS: was just trying to get the code working on dev machine, moving to local after prototype is working.

Comment: welcome, now you can accept that.  :)

Comment: its really weird, but putting the new code into Recent.php did not make the change appear. I have disabled all cache and flushed it, still the same result. Any ideas?

in recent.phtml it requests orders through:

             <?php $_orders = $this->getOrders(); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<?php  $_orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')            
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_firstname', 'order_address/firstname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_lastname', 'order_address/lastname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
        ->setPageSize('10')        
        ->load(0);
?>
```

added: 0 inside of the ->load()